# iTunes Internet Radio on iOS

Tags: ios, itunes, music.app, itunes-radio

iTunes desktop app has a built-in Internet Radio where users have access to a vast collection of free, streaming Internet radio stations?

[Listen to Internet radio in iTunes on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/itunes/listen-to-internet-radio-itns2946)

[image]

Is there a counterpart for the same available in iOS? Say in the Music app. If not is there a 3rd party app which provides this feature and have access to similar stations?

I often listen to a bunch on stations while on my Mac. I looking to  have the same ability available on my iPhone.

Please note, I'm not looking to subscribe to Apple Music. I am exploring if:

- The same feature from iTunes desktop app is available in iOS/1st party apps.
- 3rd party apps which can let me listen to the streaming Internet Radio stations that are available under iTunes for desktop.

Comment: What kind of research have you done so far? The app store has a whole bunch of Internet Radio apps for instance

Comment: Surprisingly, even if you _"subscribe to Apple Music"_, you still don't get the **Internet Radio** feature of iTunes on your iOS devices (you do get **iTunes Radio**, but it has an extremely limited list of stations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but requires a bit of copy/paste work.

- Select the radio stream in iTunes on desktop.
- Select the Edit menu, choose the Song Info entry (or just press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>). This will show you the location URL of the stream.  For example, the first stream in the 80s Flashback section is **A_A 80s** with the URL of http://listen.shoutcast.com/a-a80svs90s.
- Click the URL and it will select all of the text.
- Copy the URL to the clipboard (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)
- If you have your desktop setup to use Handoff to your iPhone, open the Web browser on the phone (Safari and Chrome both work) and paste in the URL. The page will become a simple media playback bar.
- If you don't use Handoff, open the Web browser on your desktop, open the bookmark manager, create a new bookmark with the URL of the stream. Hopefully you have your devices configured to sync your browser bookmarks, if so, the stream bookmark will appear in the iPhone browser.
- Finally if you don't have the devices configured for sync, you can copy/paste the stream URLs into a new email message on your desktop and then send it to yourself. Open the email on your phone and click on the stream URL, which should load up in your Web browser.

As [nohillside mentioned above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347520/itunes-internet-radio-on-ios#comment455175_347520), it might be easier to manage the streams using an Internet Radio app from the AppStore. You should be able to add the stream URLs from iTunes into any Radio app.

Comment: Or just search for the station name in the iOS app :-)

Comment: Brilliant answer on so many levels!